# Remove last column of 2D matrix, or last element of 1D vector

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function:

`remove_last(x):`

if `x` is a  1D vector, then I want it to remove the last element in it.
sometime `x` might be a matrix of such vector that I want the last element removed from.
In which case I need to remove the last column.

Example of use:

```
aa = np.asarray([1,2,3])
print remove_last(aa)
#Output: [1 2]

bb = np.asarray([aa,2*aa,3*aa,4*aa])
print remove_last(aa)
#Output: [[1 2], [2 4], [3 6], [4 8]]
```

So far I have:

```
def remove_last(x):
    assert(x.ndim<=2)
    if x.ndim==1:
        return x[:-1]
    else:
        return x[:,:-1]
```

which works, but it isn't very nice.

There must be a better way, using numpy's famous slicing mechanic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is.
What you are looking for is the `...` [ellipsis slicing marker.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#structural-indexing-tools)
It says "Fill in a number of `:` until the number of slicing specifiers matches the dimension of the array."

With that your code becomes:

```
def remove_last(x):
    return x[...,:-1]
```

Clean and pythonic.