# Converting array of vectors to higher dimensional array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia, broadcast

Suppose in Julia you have a function which outputs a vector, like this:

```
foo(x,y) = rand(3)
```

And you broadcast it over some arrays

```
xs = [i for i=1:4, j=1:4]
ys = [j for i=1:4, j=1:4]
A = foo.(xs,ys)
```

Now `A` is an array of arrays.  **How can I turn this into a 3 dimensional array?**  More generally, is there a solution for higher dimensional situations?  E.g. for a similar function `foo` that outputs an n dimensional array, broadcast over m dimensional arrays `xs` and `ys`, how can one convert the broadcasted output to an n+m dimensional array?

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43536746/how-to-convert-from-arrayarrayint64-2-1-to-arrayint64-2?rq=1), but `vcat` and `hcat` only work on one dimension.  I've tried the [Destruct.jl](https://github.com/spalato/Destruct.jl) package, but again it only works on one dimension.  I've tried all the obvious indexing tricks I can think of, but e.g. `(foo.(xs,ys))[:,:][1]` just returns `(foo.(xs,ys))[1]`, which is not what I want.

Comment: Have you tried `cat(a,b,dims=n)`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use SplitApplyCombine.jl like this:

```
julia> using SplitApplyCombine

julia> A
4×4 Matrix{Vector{Float64}}:
 [0.718738, 0.911636, 0.0113524]   [0.356858, 0.454262, 0.599563]   …  [0.455822, 0.475587, 0.567987]
 [0.126141, 0.435478, 0.854416]    [0.621569, 0.210589, 0.404811]      [0.682072, 0.245013, 0.962997]
 [0.361148, 0.753464, 0.752801]    [0.0643847, 0.193872, 0.820067]     [0.676852, 0.942302, 0.093561]
 [0.0223175, 0.0972373, 0.215464]  [0.737345, 0.737404, 0.996896]      [0.183609, 0.335617, 0.720999]

julia> combinedims(A)
3×4×4 Array{Float64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 0.718738   0.126141  0.361148  0.0223175
 0.911636   0.435478  0.753464  0.0972373
 0.0113524  0.854416  0.752801  0.215464

[:, :, 2] =
 0.356858  0.621569  0.0643847  0.737345
 0.454262  0.210589  0.193872   0.737404
 0.599563  0.404811  0.820067   0.996896

[:, :, 3] =
 0.135787  0.851451   0.930372  0.498012
 0.74397   0.552808   0.960158  0.506592
 0.502612  0.0145137  0.915655  0.538791

[:, :, 4] =
 0.455822  0.682072  0.676852  0.183609
 0.475587  0.245013  0.942302  0.335617
 0.567987  0.962997  0.093561  0.720999
```

Is this what you wanted to get?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to concatenate such that for the result `B`, we have

```
B[i,j,:] == A[i,j]
```

Here's how I'd write this by hand, with a couple of test cases:

```
julia> function stack_inner(A)
           m = ndims(A)
           n = ndims(eltype(A))
           s_outer = size(A)
           s_inner = size(A[begin])
           T = eltype(eltype(A))
           B = similar(A, T, s_outer..., s_inner...)
           .. = fill(:, n)
           for ix in CartesianIndices(A)
               view(B, ix, (..)...) .= A[ix]
           end
           
           return B
       end
stack_inner (generic function with 1 method)

julia> stack_inner(foo.(xs, ys))
4×4×3 Array{Float64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 0.146902  0.454526   0.191392  0.0322454
 0.824091  0.482875   0.700646  0.431301
 0.701653  0.0762824  0.194861  0.62421
 0.663212  0.0853607  0.313588  0.368867

[:, :, 2] =
 0.828077  0.74424   0.255279  0.666977
 0.854976  0.302373  0.649691  0.41975
 0.759374  0.200208  0.502984  0.886694
 0.315596  0.683564  0.956973  0.170769

[:, :, 3] =
 0.765305  0.327369   0.824123  0.0537041
 0.642428  0.595402   0.235029  0.53
 0.603463  0.87867    0.913007  0.548221
 0.058201  0.0320288  0.636     0.39045

julia> A = foo.(xs,ys)
4×4 Matrix{Vector{Float64}}:
 [0.369792, 0.692929, 0.330885]      [0.986054, 0.628871, 0.604634]   [0.367734, 0.974091, 0.621425]  [0.848115, 0.76681, 0.070687]
 [0.00585058, 0.0253985, 0.0470831]  [0.10664, 0.373489, 0.111656]    [0.719105, 0.126512, 0.660547]  [0.999209, 0.0836153, 0.56231]
 [0.88527, 0.745378, 0.380452]       [0.861579, 0.252228, 0.303043]   [0.506468, 0.645717, 0.443472]  [0.322553, 0.80937, 0.90342]
 [0.783752, 0.553846, 0.830212]      [0.868647, 0.0431845, 0.868717]  [0.533789, 0.247143, 0.968839]  [0.813371, 0.78052, 0.0166259]

julia> stack_inner(A)
4×4×3 Array{Float64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 0.369792    0.986054  0.367734  0.848115
 0.00585058  0.10664   0.719105  0.999209
 0.88527     0.861579  0.506468  0.322553
 0.783752    0.868647  0.533789  0.813371

[:, :, 2] =
 0.692929   0.628871   0.974091  0.76681
 0.0253985  0.373489   0.126512  0.0836153
 0.745378   0.252228   0.645717  0.80937
 0.553846   0.0431845  0.247143  0.78052

[:, :, 3] =
 0.330885   0.604634  0.621425  0.070687
 0.0470831  0.111656  0.660547  0.56231
 0.380452   0.303043  0.443472  0.90342
 0.830212   0.868717  0.968839  0.0166259

julia> xs = rand(2,2,3); ys = rand(2,2,3);

julia> A = foo.(xs, ys)
2×2×3 Array{Vector{Float64}, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 [0.992239, 0.0603648, 0.687885]  [0.896318, 0.825111, 0.31629]
 [0.348628, 0.580808, 0.365436]   [0.31947, 0.126727, 0.364692]

[:, :, 2] =
 [0.714268, 0.0538692, 0.404262]  [0.1527, 0.556172, 0.922746]
 [0.521115, 0.383689, 0.731707]   [0.663383, 0.764024, 0.61838]

[:, :, 3] =
 [0.23384, 0.388472, 0.413886]   [0.119036, 0.117612, 0.365978]
 [0.208551, 0.875924, 0.783887]  [0.444344, 0.466899, 0.523953]

julia> stack_inner(A)
2×2×3×3 Array{Float64, 4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 0.992239  0.896318
 0.348628  0.31947

[:, :, 2, 1] =
 0.714268  0.1527
 0.521115  0.663383

[:, :, 3, 1] =
 0.23384   0.119036
 0.208551  0.444344

[:, :, 1, 2] =
 0.0603648  0.825111
 0.580808   0.126727

[:, :, 2, 2] =
 0.0538692  0.556172
 0.383689   0.764024

[:, :, 3, 2] =
 0.388472  0.117612
 0.875924  0.466899

[:, :, 1, 3] =
 0.687885  0.31629
 0.365436  0.364692

[:, :, 2, 3] =
 0.404262  0.922746
 0.731707  0.61838

[:, :, 3, 3] =
 0.413886  0.365978
 0.783887  0.523953

julia> foo(x,y) = rand(3, 3)
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> xs = rand(1,2); ys = rand(1,2);

julia> A = foo.(xs, ys)
1×2 Matrix{Matrix{Float64}}:
 [0.886281 0.898241 0.0377659; 0.720996 0.401784 0.567878; 0.670619 0.681678 0.457421]  [0.0157844 0.23003 0.155695; 0.698028 0.535197 0.458348; 0.500317 0.880123 0.970028]

julia> stack_inner(A)
1×2×3×3 Array{Float64, 4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 0.886281  0.0157844

[:, :, 2, 1] =
 0.720996  0.698028

[:, :, 3, 1] =
 0.670619  0.500317

[:, :, 1, 2] =
 0.898241  0.23003

[:, :, 2, 2] =
 0.401784  0.535197

[:, :, 3, 2] =
 0.681678  0.880123

[:, :, 1, 3] =
 0.0377659  0.155695

[:, :, 2, 3] =
 0.567878  0.458348

[:, :, 3, 3] =
 0.457421  0.970028
```

(The funny `..` is just a hack to do what one could use EllipsisNotation.jl for.)